# Clarification on definition of closed $\mathcal{C}$-module for a category $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Hovey introduces the notion of a closed monoidal structure and a closed monoidal functor. Then he goes on to say that this naturally gives rise to the notion of closed modules over a closed monoidal category. I am a bit confused about what this means and how this definition 'interacts' with the definition of modules over monoidal model categories.

in particular I am not quite sure what additional structure a *closed* module has.
So let $\mathcal{C}$ be a closed monoidal category. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a closed $\mathcal{C}$-module. That means there is a functor

$$
\otimes: \mathcal{D}\times \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}
$$

and associativity and unit transformations, subject to the standard axioms.

Now a monoidal model category is automatically closed and if $\mathcal{M}$ is such a monoidal model category a $\mathcal{M}$-model category is by definition required to be a model category $\mathcal{N}$ making

$$
\otimes :\mathcal{N}\times\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}
$$
into a Quillen bifunctor. Is it then automatically a closed module, when forgetting the model structure?

Comment: I think for a closed $C$-module the functor $\otimes:D\times C\to D$ is supposed to have adjoints in both variables, just like the tensor product $\otimes : C\times C\to C$ of a closed monoidal category does.  An $M$-model category is by definition a closed $M$-module with the additional property that $\otimes$ is a Quillen bifunctor.